# Flattening nested entities with ids in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, functional-programming, entity, flatten

Lets say I define an entity (with nested entity) in the form:

```
{:id 1
 :a 7
 :b "Bob"
 :c {:id 2
     :d 9}
}
```

I would like to convert this to a vector of vectors of the form [[id key value]]
e.g.

```
[
  [1 :a 7]
  [1 :b "Bob"]
  [2 :d 9]
  [1 :c 2]
]
```

I think it's going to have to be some sort of recursive algorithm that branches depending on the type of the value, but I can't quite get it to work.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,

Matt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tree-seq` and `for` to the rescue!

```
 (for [m (tree-seq map? vals data)       ;; traverse nested maps
       :when (map? m)                    ;; we only care about maps
       [k v] m                           ;; traverse key-value-pairs
       :when (not= k :id)]               ;; ignore the ':id' key
   [(:id m) k (if (map? v) (:id v) v)])
 ;; => ([1 :c 2] [1 :b "Bob"] [1 :a 7] [2 :d 9])
```

This will traverse your data in a depth-first way (`tree-seq`) and then use `for` to find and process the interesting values. (I wasn't sure how you came up with `[1 :c 2]` so I assumed you wanted the ID of the submap there.)